# Android 11 local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID

Tags: android

Precondition:
compileSdkVersion was changed from 29 to 30

Crash happened first time after start activity from notification which contain some serializable object. Only on Android 11.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object

Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
Parcelable encountered IOException reading a Serializable object 

Caused by java.io.InvalidClassException
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6462537143028207571, local class serialVersionUID = 1667804997994612949
```